# Why is this template function call not working?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have the following code in my models.py:

```
class DealInstance(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()

    def get_remaining_time(self):
        return end - start # returns a datetime.timedelta object
```

I now want to use the get_remaining_time function in my template:

```
<p>Time diff: {{ deal_instance.get_remaining_time.days }}</p>
```

However this doesn't work, even if I change `get_remaining_time` to return a string literal.

This code is based off of https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#accessing-method-calls.

Comment: do you get any error messages? (e.g. you should probably have `return self.end - self.start`)

Comment: No error messages.  It loads the view just fine, except it doesn't display any output from the template's function call.  `return self.end - self.start` didn't make a difference.

Comment: what have you done in terms of debugging? (e.g. what if your method simply outputs a string? a datetime?)

Comment: I tried to have the function return a string literal and some other things- nothing produced any output in the rendered view.

Comment: Perhaps your `deal_instance` does not have start and/or end set? In this case `get_remaining_time` may return `null`. Try debuging it. Put a print in `get_remaining_time` method before `return`. Also try using `{{ deal_instance.get_remaining_time }}` without `days` and see what's happening.

Comment: None of those worked.  For now I'm just going to append a `remaining_time` field to each deal_instance object in the view, so I can access it in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing (from within the template) each portion of the expression. E.g. `[{{deal_instance}}] [{{deal_instance.get_remaining_days}}] [{{deal_instance.get_remaining_days.days}}]` (Note: I use [] around expressions so that empty strings are visible). You may find that one of them is invalid and the somewhat-too-friendly template resolver is simply returning an empty string.

Also, take a look at the source of the returned page. If the output of the expression is an object reference, then by default it will be printed out in the `< some sort of class info >` format, which most browsers will consider as a bogus HTML tag and ignore it.